# Getting datetime edge cases with laraval eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, datetime

Im currently building a reservation system for a restaurant and i have a question regarding edge cases in the reservation. to filter out tables that are not available i try to get the reservations and filter out the tables. for example, if reservation a starts at june 17 11:00 and ends june 17 12:00
you should not be able to book that table for that time period, however you should be able to end an earlier reservation at 11:00 and start a new reservation at 12:00 for that table.

this is the code that i had in laravel that did this (sort of):

```
$startDate = $request->query('start_date');
    $endDate = $request->query('end_date');
    $people_amount = $request->query('people_amount');
    $reservation_id = $request->query('reservation_id');

    $tables = Table::all();
    $reservations = Reservation::whereBetween('start_datetime', [$startDate, $endDate])->orWhereBetween('end_datetime', [$startDate, $endDate])->get();
```

this worked perfectly except it wil not account for edge cases so i did this:

```
 $reservations = Reservation::where([['start_datime', '>', $startDate],
        ['start_datetime', '<', $endDate]
        ])->orWhere([['start_datetime', '>', $startDate],
        ['end_datetime', '>', $startDate]]);
```

somewhere i went wrong but for the life of me i cant figure it out. any help would be greatly appreciated!

(this is the entire code):

```
public function showTables(Request $request)
    {
        $startDate = $request->query('start_date');
        $endDate = $request->query('end_date');
        $people_amount = $request->query('people_amount');
        $reservation_id = $request->query('reservation_id');

        $tables = Table::all();
       // $reservations = Reservation::whereBetween('start_datetime', [$startDate, $endDate])->orWhereBetween('end_datetime', [$startDate, $endDate])->get();
        //  dd($reservations);
        $reservations = Reservation::where([['start_datetime', '<', $startDate],
        ['start_datetime', '>', $endDate]
        ])->orWhere([['start_datetime', '<', $startDate],
        ['end_datetime', '<', $startDate]])->get();

        if (isset($reservation_id)) {
            $reservations = $reservations->filter(function ($item) use ($reservation_id) {
                return $item->id != $reservation_id;
            });
        }
        //  dd($reservations);

        foreach ($reservations as $key => $reservation) {

            foreach ($tables as $key => $table) {

                if ($table->seats_amount < $people_amount) {
                    unset($tables[$key]);
                }

                if ($table->id === $reservation->table_id) {
                    unset($tables[$key]);
                }
            }
        }

        TableCollection::wrap('tables');
        return new TableCollection($tables);
    }
```

edit, the fix:

```
 $reservations = Reservation::where([['start_datetime', '>', $startDate],
        ['start_datetime', '<', $endDate]
        ])->orWhere([['end_datetime', '>', $startDate],
        ['end_datetime', '<', $endDate]])->orWhere([['start_datetime', '<', $startDate],
        ['end_datetime', '>', $startDate]])->orWhere([['start_datetime', '=', $startDate],
        ['end_datetime', '=', $endDate]])->get();
```

Comment: If you want to allow my reservation that ends at `11:00:00`, based on that an existing one starts at `11:00:00` - then why are you using `>` and `<` in your comparisons? Is `11:00:00` less than `11:00:00`? No it isn’t, at most it is less-than-or-equal.

Comment: in most cases yes, but it should ignore edgecases, as the list i get back from that query is being used to filter out the tables that already have an reservation at that time

Comment: I find it is often easiest to figure this kind of stuff out, if you simply take a piece of paper, and just “draw” the possible cases. Draw a line of a couple inches in the middle of your sheet of paper - that is your already existing booking in the database. Now you draw a couple of lines below that, to model the possible cases for your new booking, that you want to check now … https://pastebin.com/12sS2MMS Which of these cases are valid and which aren’s should be pretty obvious from looking at it, right? So try and formulate the appropriate conditions based on that.

Comment: well i gotta say, that worked, drawed it out on a piece of paper and got the problem fixed thanks!

Comment: @RobinWelten Could you answer this question with your fix? It would help future users that have the same problem.